# What does obj_$(variable_name) do in a makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have encountered the following line in a make file:

OBJECTDIR = obj_$(TARGET)

What does the command  obj_$(TARGET)  do?

Unfortunately this command is not listed in the GNU make manual:
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/

Comment: It's just a variable definition like any other. `OBJECTDIR` will expand to `obj_<whatever TARGET expands to>`.

Answer (score 0):

This is just normal variable expansion. Say that the `TARGET` variable has value `foo`, e.g. somewhere before that line you have:

```
TARGET := foo
```

Then `obj_$(TARGET)` will be expanded to `obj_foo`, which is equivalent to:

```
OBJECTDIR = obj_foo
```

I suggest you look up [how to use variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Using-Variables.html) in the Make manual (the expansion will work differently depending on the flavor of `TARGET`).